# Custom method in PreAuthorize is not working "Failed to evaluate expression 'isAdmin()'"

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new UserPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(context);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

And UserPermission class

```
@Component("UsrPermission")
public class UserPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetObject, Object permission) {
        if (!targetObject.toString().equals("true") && targetObject.toString().equals(permission.toString())) {
            return true;
        } else if (!targetObject.toString().equals("true")) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
        return hasPermission;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return CustomSecurityPrincipal.getSecurityPrincipal().isAdmin();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType,
            Object permission) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

"hasPermission(x, y, z)" is working like charm. But, I tried to create new custom method, and since it is registerd in MethodSecurityConfig. I am trying to call it directly

```
@PreAuthorize("isAdmin()")
```

Error:-

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method isAdmin() cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:225) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:134) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:94) ~
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:300) ~[spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:59) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:72) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:40) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at
```

...

Comment: In order to create the new custom expression, we need to start by implementing the root note where the evaluation of all security expressions. Have a look here. It has been nicely explained. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create a new custom expression, you need to create a custom implementation of `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` and add a new operation to it. Note that you can extend `SecurityExpressionRoot` to support default expressions:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot
        extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;

    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return returnObject;
    }

    void setThis(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
        return target;
    }

    /**
     * Custom 'isAdmin()' expression
     */
    public boolean isAdmin() {
        // TODO: Implement
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next, you need extend `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and make it to use `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot`:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl());
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        return root;
    }
}
```

Finally, you should use `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` in the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still going above my head. I can understand partially. Is there any blog or somewhere I can see any example?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Have you tried using the provided example?

Comment: instead of DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler, I should use CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot. But,where should I call isAdmin() ?

Comment: I am so sorry. I missed your points. You have mentioned properly.

Comment: Thanks, Anar. Your solution worked like a charm. Since I am new to this I took some time.

Comment: Interesting web with explanations: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression